# Объясните пятую строку,у меня все работает ,но я просто пытаюсь точнее понять код

Tags: python, синтаксис

[Код проверяет палиндромы,но это не важно,в целом я понимаю как он работает ,но мне просто интересно как работает 5 строка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AyyX.png)

Объясните ,я буду рад и счастлив на всю жизнь)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))0

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть текстом, а не картинкой и не ссылкой.

Answer (score 1):

Эта команда просто *убирает из текста «запрещенные» символы,* которые находятся в кортежи `c`.

Подробнее:

1. `(... for i in text ...)`

   Когда вы проходите через строку `text`, вы постепенно получаете ее отдельные символы.
2. `(i    for i in text ...)`

   Вы хотите те же символы получить в генераторе списка...
3. `(i    for i in text     if i not in c)`

   ... но только тогда, когда такой символ не находится в списке `c`.

Таким образом, вы из строки в переменной `text` создали *генератор отдельных символов этой строки,* но не всех, а только тех, которые *не находятся в списке «запрещенных» символов `c`.*

Как теперь использовать этот генератор, чтобы обратно получили из его отдельных символов комплектную строку?

Для этого в Питоне метод `.join()` - он из вашего генератора создает строку, в которой будут находиться все символы, отделенные между собой тем, что стоит перед точкой в `.join()`.

Но вы их *не хотите отделять,* что то же самое как между ними добавить пустую строку. Потому перед точкой вы используете **пустую строку**:

```
".join(i for i in text if i not in c)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Внешние скобки там лишние
2. Читайте про [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
3. Читайте про [генераторные выражения](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/)

Всё, больше там ничего нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
text=''.join(i for i in text if not i in c)
```

Эквивалентно коду

---

```
text='asdf'

c=(',','?','{')
ss=() #Промежуточная переменная
for i in text:
    if not i in c:
        ss+=(i,)# Добавить в кортеж, в оригинале это generator object
        print(ss)
text=''.join(ss)
print(text)
```

---

```
('a',)
('a', 's')
('a', 's', 'd')
('a', 's', 'd', 'f')
asdf
```